# crash app when use docx4j in android studio

Tags: java, android, docx4j

I'm developing an app for android. I want create a docx file with my app and i use Docx4j for this job. my app hasn't any error when compiled but when run app and touch button for create file, app is crashed.

this is error when crash:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: ir.hezare.kateb, PID: 18903
                  javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found
                      at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:72)
                      at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:176)
                      at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:92)
                      at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:136)
                      at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPartXPathAware.unmarshal(JaxbXmlPartXPathAware.java:432)
                      at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPartXPathAware.unmarshal(JaxbXmlPartXPathAware.java:346)
                      at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.StyleDefinitionsPart.unmarshalDefaultStyles(StyleDefinitionsPart.java:155)
                      at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:457)
                      at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:406)
                      at ir.hezare.kateb.Class.CreateDoc.runDoc(CreateDoc.java:97)
                      at ir.hezare.kateb.Activity.PrintActivity.btnSaveDoc(PrintActivity.java:754)
                      at ir.hezare.kateb.Activity.PrintActivity.access$000(PrintActivity.java:81)
                      at ir.hezare.kateb.Activity.PrintActivity$1.onClick(PrintActivity.java:153)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

I use this Library in my app:

```
compile group: 'org.docx4j', name: 'docx4j', version: '3.3.6'
compile group: 'org.docx4j', name: 'docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext', version: '3.3.6'
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.1'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
```

and this is my code:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
MainDocumentPart mdp = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

mdp.addParagraphOfText("hello world");

Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new java.io.File(filename), Docx4J.FLAG_SAVE_ZIP_FILE);
```

Please help me.
thanks.

Comment: for me it looks like `Docx4j` is using something, which is not supported on Android (`MXParserFactory` provider)

Comment: Suspect MOXy might be looking for that?  Check the META-INF in the MOXy related jars on your classpath